# Higher Schwarzenberger conditions for vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Has anyone computed higher Schwarzenberger conditions for vector bundles on projective space, even for rank 2 bundles?  [Schneider](http://www.numdam.org/article/SB_1978-1979__21__80_0.pdf) lists them for 2-bundles up to $\mathbb{P}^5$, and for 3-bundles on $\mathbb{P}^3$, but I haven't seen any higher dimensional conditions in the literature.  Has anyone computed these, or written a computer program to compute these?